# Framework for regression testing of numerical code

Tags: python, numpy, testing, numerical-methods, nose

My python code is performing fairly complex numerical calculations, and in many cases I am unable to provide known solutions to enable unit testing (especially for intermediate results).

However, I have found that I can catch a lot of bugs with nose, by performing regression testing using the following workflow:

1. Write test code to solve some relatively small problem
2. Run once, inspect the results (often in the form of a matplotlib plot), and decide by comparison with analytical results or other numerical software or physical intuition that the results are correct to within acceptable numerical accuracy.
3. Save the resulting numpy arrays to text files to act as a reference (FWIW I was avoiding numpy's saving routines as a workaround for [this bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5655), but as this has been fixed in a released version think I can use them now).
4. The test code performs the calculation, and compares it with the reference data read in from the file using numpy's `assert_allclose`.

The test function is written in such a way as that by default it performs the test, but by passing non-default values for arguments I can plot the results and overwrite the reference file if it becomes necessary. The reference file is checked into git so there is little risk of accidentally overwriting the test values without noticing.

However, I find myself writing a lot of boilerplate code to implement the above functionality, which outweighs the actual test code itself. Cleaning this up would make it much easier to increase test coverage.

**Is there some python testing framework or plugin for nose that could easily automate the above workflow?**

Answer (score 2):

A few months ago I wrote the [nrtest](https://nrtest.readthedocs.org) utility in an attempt to make this workflow easier. It sounds like it might help you too.

Here's a quick overview. Each test is defined by its input files and its expected output files. Following execution, output files are stored in a portable benchmark directory. A second step then compares this benchmark to a reference benchmark. A recent update has enabled user extensions, so you can define comparison functions for your custom data.

I hope it helps.